# How to remove Xcode 3.0 on Snow Leopard when uninstall scripts are missing?

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, uninstallation

As for Snow Leopard there is no updated and free Xcode available and as I need it for Ror only, I decided for osx-gcc-installer (much smaller too) and homebrew warns one should remove Xcode first.

The trouble is, the regular `$ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all` won't work as the uninstall scripts what it is supposed to run are missing (don't ask me why).

I can't even reinstall Xcode as the 3.0 is for Leopard and as far as I knew the new versions will not overwrite the old but will add another Xcode next to it.

App Cleaner won't work because Xcode is complex enough not to be considered as one program by the app.

Another way would be manually trash everything what resembles Xcode - too bad as the trouble started with the issue that I can not install new Ruby version and I need it nice and clean to clear things up a little.

Is there a solution?

Comment: You can install Xcode 3.2 from your Snow Leopard install DVD. That would give you access to the uninstall scripts.

Comment: Thank you, it was a good advice and worked well: removed ALL the xcode. After reinstalling GCC, rvm, ruby and rails I finally have everything up and running fluently!

Answer (score 1):

sudo rm -rf /Developer /Libary/Developer ~/Libary/Developer

I dont think it has any other data stored somewhere.

**THEN** install xcode4

Comment: thank you for the fast response. are sure about it? I can not cite the exact source but somebody warned that the old xcode is spread all over harddisk. I knew since xcode 4 you can just throw away the folder and its done, but before that?